# how to avoid regex matching "Revert "Revert"

Tags: python

I have the following code which matches both line1 and line2,I *ONLY* want to match line2 but not line1, can anyone provide guidance on how to do this?

```
import re   

line1 = '''Revert "Revert <change://problem/47614601> [tech feature][V3 Driver] Last data path activity timestamp update is required for feature""'''
line2 = '''Revert <change://problem/47614601> [tech feature][V3 Driver] Last data path activity timestamp update is required for feature"'''

if re.findall(".*?(?:Revert|revert)\s*\S*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8})", line2):
    match = re.findall(".*?(?:Revert|revert)\s*\S*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8})", line2)
    print "Revert radar match%s"%match
    revert_radar = True

print revert_radar
```

Comment: `line.startswith('Revert'} and line.count('Revert') == 1`?

Comment: No,that wont work for all other cases,I need to fix the regex as it handles other cases aswell

Comment: Perhaps a negative look ahead assertion at the beginning to exclude the unwanted line.

Comment: Is the structure for all *unwanted* cases the same? `word your looking for followed by a space followed by a double quote and the same word`?

Comment: Are they individual lines or lines within a larger body of text?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
>>> regex = "(?!:(?:R|r)evert.*)(?:Revert|revert)\s*\S*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8})"
>>> re.match(regex, line1) is None
True
>>> re.match(regex, line2).groups()
('47614601',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative look behind: word NOT proceeded by sameword-space-doublequote

```
r'''(?<![Rr]evert ")[Rr]evert\s<change:[/][/]problem[/]\d{8}.*"'''
```

Negative look ahead: pattern you want NOT followed by a double doublequote

```
r'''[Rr]evert\s<change:[/][/]problem[/]\d{8}.*?\w"(?!")'''
```

- this doesn't work if the *unwanted* line immediately precedes the wanted line without an intervening newline character.
- it does work if the *unwanted* line follows the wanted line.

If looking at individual lines, look for the pattern at the start of string - of the three this is the least work, most efficient for the regex engine

```
r'''^[Rr]evert\s<change:[/][/]problem[/]\d{8}.*$'''
```

If the line you are searching for is *embedded* in a long string but there is a newline character before that line you can use the previous pattern with the multiline flag.